# How should I get the difference between 2 list<Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot

there are 2 Entity list with different size and objects, for example `List<BrandEntity> baseEntityList` and `List<BrandEntity> subEntityList`, now I want to get the result which stored in baseEntityList and not in subEntityList, the different dimension is brandName. I have overwrite the equals method but it doesn't work. Here are my codes.

```
Main.class: 
  findDifferenceList(baseEntityList, subEntityList)
Method:

private <T> List<T> findDifferenceList(List<T> baseBrandList, List<T> subBrandList) {
return baseBrandList.stream().filter(item -> !subBrandList.contains(item)).collect(toList());
```

}

```
BrandEntity:

@Slf4j
public class BrandEntity {
  @JsonSetter("shopid")
  Long shopId;


  @JsonSetter("brand")
  String brandName;

  @JsonIgnore Long principalId;

  // getter and setter

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    BrandEntity that = (BrandEntity) o;
    return Objects.equals(brandName, that.brandName);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(brandName);
  }
}
```

Comment: according to that method, if my lists are {} and {A,B}, the difference is {} i.e. nothing. Bit strange

Comment: Code looks okay. What have you used as testdata?

Comment: @Michael This method doesn't calculate bidirectional difference. It returns only elements from list1 that are not in list2.

Comment: that's what I need

Comment: @SergeHarnyk Yes, you just rephrase what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you are doing is comparing the Strings based on their reference equality - as seen in Objects(below). But you need to compare them on their value equality like `brandName.equals(that.brandName)`.

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Neverthenless I would rather use a existing libary to compare the List, like Apache's commons `CollectionUtils`:

```
CollectionUtils.removeAll(List<T> baseBrandList, List<T> subBrandList);
```

Comment: you are right, it caused by equals String value, I just generate the method through IntelljIdea, actually need to modify it

Answer (score 1):

this is some tricky codes, if i want do it, i will remove all `subEntityList` from `baseEntityList`

or if you want to find difference in two lists you can do it for both of them

```
var diffWithBase = subEntityList.removeAll(baseEntityList);
var diffWithSubList = baseEntityList.removeAll(subEntityList);
// print
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try oldschool Java way

```
List<BrandEntity> diff = new ArrayList<>(baseEntityList);
difference.removeAll(subEntityList);
return diff;
```

Comment: tried, still can't work, the wired thing is that this.brandName is aways null but that.brandname value is correct in equals method when I debug it

Comment: @ZhangXin maybe some issues with JSON deserialization? Can you show your data?

Comment: thanks, it's done, the issue caused by equals method

Answer (score 0):

```
List<BrandEntity> findDifferenceList(List<BrandEntity> list1, List<BrandEntity> list2) {
 return list1.stream().filter(i -> !list2.contains(i))
            .concat(list2.stream.filter(i -> !list1.contains(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You need to do what you did both directions ;). Whats not in A and in B and whats not in B and in A.

Comment: nope, I just want to get the elements only store in list1 and not in list2

Comment: what do you expect when baseBrandList is {}  and subBrandList {A, B} ?